# Bash: making output of "ls" colorful and also multiple columns

Tags: bash

I would like to see the output of `ls` in columns with color highlight for MacOS Bash Shell.

**For color**

```sh
ls -GFS # gives colorful output of one column
```

**for columns**

```sh
ls | paste - - -   # gives 3 columns without hightlight
```

How can we make it both colored and 3 columns?

It would be nice, if I can make a function and put in `.bash_profile` so that
when ever I do `lss` I can see output list in 3 columns.

such as:

```sh
alias lss='ls -GFS'
```

**Update**

```sh
ls -GFS | paste - - - # This gives 3 columns but no hightlight

ls -GFS # this gives one column with hightlight
```

Comment: you mean yo do nt have colors when passing output to a pipe?

Comment: Yes, I do not get highlight when I pass through pipe, only black and white for all three columns.

Comment: `ls -GFS` already outputs multiple columns when the filenames are short enough  to allow it.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yeah, but my file names are short and it gives one long column of file lists with hightlights.

Comment: Yes, `ls` disables color codes when writing to a non-TTY sink. That's normal/expected/good behavior, because programs you pipe to almost never interpret those codes correctly. Use `--color=always` to override it (on a GNU system), but at your own risk.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy And in this very case, unfortunately that  "feature" is the "bug" for me. I am looking a way to give 3 columns and also hightlight, using any possible method.

Comment: `ls --color=always | paste - - -` will *sorta* do what you want, except `paste` doesn't know which characters are and aren't nonprintable (because they're changing the color rather than moving the cursor), so your columns are prone to being aligned wrong. At some point, you may need to write your own terminal-aware `paste` equivalent if this is something you *really* want to do; at least, being a software development question as opposed to a command-line-tool usage one, that would actually be on-topic here.

Comment: (Interactive-usage questions are generally a better fit for [unix.se] than here).

Comment: (As another aside, this is much more a question about your operating system than about bash; `ls` isn't provided by bash, and its behavior depends much more on your OS version than anything else; similarly, `paste` is provided by your operating system, not your shell -- so that OS should be specified in the question).

Answer (score 1):

You can force macOS ls to show colors when piping by setting `CLICOLOR_FORCE`:

```
CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -GFS | cat
```

The equivalent for GNU ls is:

```
ls --color=always | cat
```

However, note that macOS `ls -GFS` will automatically adjusts the number of columns to fit the filenames and terminal width:

```
bash-3.2 $ ls -GFS
a pretty long filename
an even longer filename that takes up half the terminal
file1*
file2*
file3*

bash-3.2 $ rm an\ even\ longer\ filename\ that\ takes\ up\ half\ the\ terminal
bash-3.2 $ ls -GFS
a pretty long filename  file2*
file1*                  file3*

bash-3.2 $ rm a\ pretty\ long\ filename
bash-3.2 $ ls -GFS
file1* file2* file3*
```

Comment: Upvoted, also interestingly, my bash terminal does not give multiple columns for short file names like your output given above.

Comment: @astro123 How about if you run `env -i ls` instead?

Comment: `/bin/ls -GFS` works. Gives different colors to folders and different files.

Comment: @astro123 You probably have `alias ls='ls -1'` or something to explicitly disable columns. `/bin/ls` will override any aliases and therefore give use default settings

Comment: Is it also risky to use `CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -GFS | cat` like as color always as Charles pointed out?

Comment: Yes, it's the same inherent problem of trying to align characters that may or may not show up